# Grammatically incorrect "Recommend close" button description in low quality post review page

Tags: bug

> - **Recommend Close** to recommend that this question be closed

[image: img]

Perhaps it should be "**Recommend Close** to recommend that this question *should* be closed"?

Comment: Please forgive my lack of knowledge of English on this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that seems fine to me. And a [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=%22recommend%20that%20*%20be%20closed%22) shows it's not an uncommon construct, going as far back as 1808 in the Books search.

Comment: Not a native speaker myself, so it sounded weird to my ears. You're right, it seems pretty widespread too. Also [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend) reports it as a possible construct, so I think there should be no more questioning.